# I have Battlefield 3 Limited Edition but it says that I have to buy Back to Karkand?

Tags: battlefield-3

I have Battlefield 3: Limited Edition, and I want to play on the Back to Karkand maps, but it does not let me.

It says that I have to buy Back to Karkand, while the Limited Edition contains the DLC, already.

I purchased the game preowned.

Can anybody tell me why it is not reading the DLC part of the Limited Edition?

Comment: I bought it from G2A, but in game I can do the assignments to unlock the new guns, but can't play on the DLC.

Comment: I dont know it was long time ago, lets say it was preowned, is that why I can't play on Karkand ? And I don't understand why everyone gives me (-) for that question ?

Comment: You downvoted my question but i'm still friendly and accepted your answer. All this could happen without downvote no ? The question is answered.

Comment: That still doesn't change anything. Downvotes are used to define a question as being either unclear, not useful, unresearched or badly-written.

Comment: @4NON1MOU5, please don't over-simplify you question to accommodate the answer. This question made amounts of sense, before the edit; after the edit, nobody could understand what you were asking. Also note that the trend of this site suggests that **if you ask about your downvotes, you will ultimately only receive more downvotes**. It is not good form, but there's not much else we can do, given the nature of being a community-driven site. I will always downvote heavily un-researched questions, regardless of context; This answer came directly from the back of the Battlefield 3 game case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Back to Karkand is the first expansion pack for Battlefield 3. In other words, it is DLC, and you must purchase it separately.

Sometimes, particular versions of the game will come with DLC. Rather then being provided on the actual disc, the game will include a DLC code. This code can be entered on the platform-specific marketplace, and will give your account access to the DLC.

In this case of preowned games, these codes are often absent, or have already been used. Developers often use this mechanic to penalise players who purchase the game second hand, as they do not make money from these transactions. Ultimately, to access the full game, players such as yourself will still have to pay an extra sum to buy the DLC; even if the game advertises its inclusion.